# Codimension of variety versus linear independence of defining homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, affine-varieties, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $p_1, ..., p_m \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be $m < n$ linearly independent homogeneous polynomials each of degree exactly $d$, and assume they have nonzero intersection.  Is the codimension of the affine variety determined by $p_1, ..., p_m$ at least $m$?

If this does not hold in general, can we lower bound the codimension of the variety in terms of $d$ (e.g., what if $d=2$)?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true, in any form. First, over $\mathbb{R}$, every algebraic variety is defined by a single equation, regardless of its co/dimension. The reason is because over $\mathbb{R}$, polynomials $p_1, ..., p_m$ vanish if and only if $p_1^2 + ... + p_m^2$ vanishes!

But the situation is not better over $\mathbb{C}$ either, now there are simply new issues. For example, there is the twisted cubic curve, which is a curve in $\mathbb{CP}^3$ which is cut out by exactly three equations, all of which are quadratic equations, and no two of them suffice, so the codimension is $2$, rather than the expected $3$. In general, varieties with the property you ask for are called "complete intersections," and are related to a slew of algebraic properties of the ideal they generate inside $\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]$, or its homogenous counterpart. For example, if the polynomials generate a regular sequence, then you have at least a local complete intersection.

Unfortunately, I don't know any super short exposition of these ideas. There are a bunch of moving parts, some algebraic and some geometric, and I learned them from Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra, and Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Feel free to refine the question, or ask for more details or clarification. While there is a lot of stuff beneath the surface here, I might be able to provide specific insights if you have more specific follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure this answers my question. I don't see how the observation about $p_1^2+...+p_m^2$ would rule out such a result. I especially have the case $m=2$ in mind. I haven't been able to find a set of two linearly independent homogeneous polynomials of the same degree whose solution set has codimension one (or zero).

Comment: @ccriscitiello $x^2+xy$ and $xy+y^2$, for one.

Comment: @KReiser I see, thanks!